# Redis dump file prevents slave mode

Tags: redis

I have a redis master and slave configuration. What I'm finding is that if I restart the slave while there is a dump.rdb file in the directory, the instance starts as a master with no connected slaves rather than obeying the slaveof command in the config file. If I restart the service after deleting the dump.rdb, then the slave will come back online and connect to the master as expected.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a way to allow a slave to be restarted and go directly into slave mode?

Edit: This is running on Windows.